# my python client for magento is not installing

Tags: python, magento

I downloaded the python client for magento from 
 [Here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=search&term=magento&submit=search)  But When I am downloading is using `python setup.py install` then it shows following `error`. How can i rectify this error?

error:

```
File "setup.py", line 31, in <module>
    import magento
  File "/home/sam/Downloads/magento-0.1.1/magento/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from api import API
  File "/home/sam/Downloads/magento-0.1.1/magento/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from suds.client import Client
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you getting

```
ImportError: No module named suds.client
```

as the last line of the error message? If so, perhaps you need to install [this](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install suds.
better to use pip for it

```
pip install suds
```

It is easier to use with virtualenv